# Canada Universal Child Care Benefit (UCCB): $100/month per child under age 6 from the government. Is it true?

Tags: canada, children, benefits

Somebody told me that if I have a child under age 6, then I'm entitled to get a $100/month
benefit from the Canadian government. Is that true?  How do I apply for it?

Comment: Note: I've seen the UCCB also referred to as the **Universal Child Tax Benefit (UCTB)**, but the former appears to be the definitive/current and more often referenced name.

Comment: On October 30th, 2014, major changes were announced to UCCB. See: **[How are Canada Universal Child Care Benefit (UCCB) & related tax measures changing in 2015?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39219/how-are-canada-universal-child-care-benefit-uccb-related-tax-measures-changi)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it's true.**  The benefit in question is Canada's **Universal Child Care Benefit (UCCB)**.  The UCCB was introduced in the [2006 Federal Budget](http://www.fin.gc.ca/budget06/bp/bpc3c-eng.asp).  The UCCB provides "***all families*** with $100 per month for each child under age 6."  Benefits began in July, 2006.

What's confusing is how to apply for the UCCB.  When UCCB was introduced, there existed another benefit called the *Canada Child Tax Benefit (CCTB)*.  When introducing UCCB, the government decided it would be more efficient to have a **single application process** for all child benefits. In order to get UCCB, you would apply under the existing application process for CCTB.

Unfortunately:

1. The application form for CCTB doesn't mention the UCCB at all!
2. The CCTB is *income-tested*, meaning if your family makes more than a certain amount of income, you don't qualify for CCTB, which may **incorrectly lead you to believe you shouldn't apply!**

You should apply anyway for CCTB, even if you don't expect CCTB benefits.  Applying for CCTB gets you in the system to receive UCCB, which is *not income-tested.*  (But, UCCB benefits are taxable.)

Here's the necessary form: [RC66 - Canada Child Benefits Application](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/rc66/README.html). Even after updates since 2006, it *still* doesn't mention UCCB, but it does say "*Complete this form to apply for all child benefit programs.*"

Here are some other resources about the UCCB:

- [Canada Revenue Agency - Universal Child Care Benefit (UCCB)](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/uccb-puge/menu-eng.html)
- [Canadian Family - Universal Child Care Benefit 101](http://www.canadianfamily.ca/articles/article/click-here-for-600/)
- [Canadian Capitalist - Apply for the Universal Child Care Benefit (UCCB)](http://www.canadiancapitalist.com/universal-child-care-benefit-uccb/)

Comment: **By the way**, UCCB will pay benefits *retroactively* for up to 11 months, in case you were wondering if you kissed money goodbye or not.  Apply now!

Comment: On October 30th, 2014, major changes were announced to UCCB. See: **[How are Canada Universal Child Care Benefit (UCCB) & related tax measures changing in 2015?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39219/how-are-canada-universal-child-care-benefit-uccb-related-tax-measures-changi)**

Answer (score 3):

That would be the Universal Child Care Benefit (UCCB)

> The UCCB is designed to help Canadian families, as they try to balance work and family life, by supporting their child care choices through direct financial support. The UCCB is for children under the age of 6 years and is paid in instalments of $100 per month per child.

Info found here.

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/uccb-puge/menu-eng.html

There also is a tax credit that can be used to help pay for children fitness expenses.

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/fitness/